# How to create a Visual Studio Setup Project registry value with the application install path?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, registry, setup-project

I have a very simple application installer that needs to add an action to the shell menu of all files (HKCR*\shell), and I've run into a brick wall: how do I insert the installed path of the application into a registry value?  I've tried everything I can think of:

- `[Path]`
- `[ApplicationFolder]`
- `[ApplicationPath]`
- `[InstallPath]`
- `[InstallRoot]`
- `[InstallFolder]`
- `[InstallTarget]`
- `[TargetPath]`

I even tried adding one that I know works in other places (`[Manufacturer]`) to make sure that the bracket-values syntax actually works in the Registry (it does).

Anyone *know*, or at the least, have any ideas that I haven't tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one you are looking for is [TARGETDIR]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that one. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a list of tags somewhere?

Comment: @LiamV http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx